# Angular 2+ with Redux using ElementRef and Observable

Tags: angular, redux, observable

I been looking into redux examples and I noticed that some project do it with observables. For example:

**HTML**

```
 <div #el_back_btn>button</div>
```

**Typescript**

```
// elements
  @ViewChild('el_back_btn') el_back_btn: ElementRef;
    const el_back_btn = Observable.fromEvent(this.el_back_btn.nativeElement, 'click')
      .subscribe(() => {
        this._navigationService.goBack();
      });
```

This feels to me to be a wrong as 
a)This looks to me like it will be listening to all events all the time 
b)We are accessing  ElementRef is that not reading the DOM like Jquery does.

What is the performance issue with this and would it slow the site strongly?

I'm thinking that it should be more with just simple (click) and all the action that it needs to preform in the action file?

Comment: There is no difference because they most likely unsubscribe from this in the code below. That is the same what angular does internally. And this has nothing to do with redux

Comment: Angular comes with built in directive and here you should definitely use `click` like that on your div: `<div (click)="someMethod()">button</div>` and within you TS just define the `someMethod` ;) You should read angular.io because trying to handle the dom like that is not a good idea and I guess that you haven't dig enough into documentation before trying to use the framework.

Comment: "trying to handle the DOM like that is not a good idea"- can you explain why? give some facts behind your statement?